# Oven Outer Glass Replacement

Tags: repair, stove

The outside glass of my GE oven ended up breaking and it doesn't seem like I'm having luck finding the exact replacement for the model I have, so my question is does anyone know if there is any that would interchange with GE JBP23DN1Ww. If anyone can help me out with this I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 10):

Entering the GE model number into [partselect.com](https://www.partselect.com/PS1021945-GE-WB56T10189-Glass-Oven-Door-White.htm?SourceCode=20&SearchTerm=JBP23DN1WW&ModelNum=JBP23DN1WW&ModelID=1589611), yields a parts diagram of the door, a statement that the door bears GE Manufacturer's part no. WB56T10189, and that this part is no longer available.

Entering part number WB56T10189 in the [ebay.com](https://www.ebay.com) search box returns a number of sellers who offer pre-owned doors and door glass.

Comment: Appliance parts - a total scam. Sure, we have part numbers, but we want you to buy a whole new oven, so we don't actually make the parts you'll need, that would hurt new oven sales....

Comment: @Ecnerwal I echo this sentiment, having had [problems](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/141032/can-a-plastic-fridge-shelf-be-definitively-repaired) with [fridge shelves](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/251582/is-acrylic-perspex-a-suitable-material-for-a-replacement-fridge-shelf) not having extant replacement parts 

Comment: @Ecnerwal For a paltry $9,999.00, it can be yours! https://partsmadness.com/oven-range-parts/wb56t10189-ge-glass-ovn-dr-wh/

Comment: @MonkeyZeus putting the "madness" in "partsmadness.com"

Comment: @bertieb The near future hopefully will provide freely downloadable models of appliance parts that could be printed on 3D printers at ones home or local makerspace / public library (or ordered from companies who print arbitrary objects and deliver via mail-order).

Comment: So far this year I've had to replace an entire range and washing machine because a part is no longer manufactured or available (even used on ebay).

Answer (score 3):

Even if there is one to find, it will be ridiculously expensive.
Faced with similar problem, I went to local "Glass-cutter", those guys cut glass for windows, from large sheets of glass, also mirrors of all sizes.. They ordered from literal glass factory a new cast glass for me. The point is, the oven window is tempered glass, it cannot be cut or drilled, since it shatters. I gave them the whole door or the oven that I've detached, along with handle. And took them whole month to find time to make a cast and pour molten glass and temper it for me. It cost me about $40 altogether. But it fits perfect and now looks more modern!

Comment: I disagree that used parts will be "ridiculously expensive." Try entering the part number in eBay, as I suggest in my answer, and see what comes up.

Comment: @Magna1 That’s pretty creative thinking - thanks for the answer!

Comment: Where do you live that you can get custom tempered glass for only $40?